# Can you hear photons in a tin can produced by a camera flash?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, photons

I had a conversation about easy demonstrations of quantum physics and have been told that you should be able to hear photons if you use an old camera flash in a tin can. 
I was skeptic but tried and I do hear a *clonk*! It disappears if I turn around the flash, but I'm still not convinced that it is not a sound wave produced by the gas discharge.

Can anybody tell me a convincing argument why it should or should not be the photons?

I did search the web and found nothing. Which made me even more skeptic.

Comment: @jameslarge thank you, it's a badly worded comment and I will  delete it,  regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Light quickly heats up the surface of the can. The air next to the surface heats up by the hot surface and expands thus pushing the surface away and creating a reactive knock on the can that you hear. This is a known effect. You would not hear it, if the surface of the can exposed to the light were surrounded by a vacuum.

So it is not the pressure of light (momentum), but the energy of light. It is possible to see the momentum of light, but not with a tin can. It requires a *full* vacuum tube with a propeller mirrored on one side and black on the other.

I just repeated your experiment. Then I put a sheet of paper in front of the flash instead of the can and the sound was even more pronounced. A black paper creates a dramatically louder sound than white paper thus confirming the explanation. In fact, the black paper heats up so much that you can see a burnt spot and smell a smoke.

[image]

Comment: The Crookes Radiometer does not demonstrate the momentum of light. It works in the way that you have described for the tin can. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiometer

Comment: @sammygerbil Thanks, I've removed the image. I can't quickly find the one that actually demonstrates the light pressure.